# How do I debug Android's WifiService operation down to the driver level?

Tags: java, android, c++, c, wifi

I need to understand how a message traverses the Android system from the service level down to the driver calls.

I have decided to start with WiFi, although my current hardware platform - a Beaglebone Black board with TI's Rowboat (Android 4.2.2) - does not have WiFi capability.

My plan is to insert logging function calls to the source code and send an Intent to WifiService through the *am* program in order to trigger the messages towards the driver.

I have found, in *init.rc*, that *ServiceManager* is started through the following code

```
service servicemanager /system/bin/servicemanager
    class core
    user system
    group system
    critical                  
    onrestart restart zygote                                           
    onrestart restart media                       
    onrestart restart surfaceflinger
    onrestart restart drm
```

Furthermore, from *frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java*, I have found this code snippet

```
try {
    Slog.i(TAG, "Wi-Fi Service");
    wifi = new WifiService(context);
    ServiceManager.addService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE, wifi);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    reportWtf("starting Wi-Fi Service", e);
}
```

which, I believe, starts *WifiService*.

However, I cannot determine how *SystemServer* is started.

Besides that, I managed to insert a log function at *frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java*, as follows

```
public WifiManager(Context context, IWifiManager service) {
    mContext = context;
    mService = service;
    Log.i(TAG, "WiFiManager Created. Calling init()"); // inserted log
    init();
}
```

and I can see it working through the use of `logcat -s WifiManager`, which results in

```
I/WifiManager(  317): WiFiManager Created. Calling init()
I/WifiManager(  396): WiFiManager Created. Calling init()
I/WifiManager(  968): WiFiManager Created. Calling init()
```

Nevertheless, I cannot determine why it is called 3 times or where the calls came from.

As for C code, I hope to see its log messages by using `dmesg`.

I have *cscope* and *ctags* configured to browse the code but I cannot manage to find what comes below *WifiService* or *WifiManager*.

It looks like I still have a long road ahead, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slide 8 from this presentation might be able to answer a couple of your questions [image: http://www.slideshare.net/marakana/android-services-black-magic-by-aleksandar-gargenta]

The sources for the WifiService and WifiController might be of help as well, you can find them in `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/wifi`. Also check the `README.txt` in there.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: @Mogsdad I'm well aware, and would really like to do so, but I'm not allowed to include images :(
Maybe you can do so? [this](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/marakanaandroidservicesblackmagic-120228005128-phpapp02/95/android-services-black-magic-by-aleksandar-gargenta-8-728.jpg?cb=1330390412) is the URL

Comment: Done... but you could still provide words to explain the relevance to the question.

Comment: Thanks, @aaahaaap.
I'd based my studies on the slides from 'marakana'.
Since it has been a year already, I cannot remember if I have been able to find all the calls.
If I find my own slides, I'll post them here.
Thanks a lot!